# Accessing members of inner generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I define two interfaces as following:

```
public interface IData
{        
   double value { set; get; }
}

public interface IInterval<C, M>
{
   C left { set; get; }
   M data { set; get; }
}
```

Then I use these two interfaces for following class declaration.

```
public class TESTClass<I, M>
       where I : IInterval<int, M>, new()
       where M : IData
{ 
   public I interval{ set; get; }

   public TESTClass()
   {
       // This is invalid, cos property value is not visible at initialization ... 
       interval = new I() { left = 0, data.value = 0 };

       // instead I have to do as: 
       interval = new I() { left = 0 };
       interval.data.value = 0;
   }
}
```

am I missing something here ?
I would appreciate if you could help me figure this out.

Comment: Why don't you also add `where M : IData` to `IInterval<C,M>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could certainly do that. Syntax is bit different.

```
public TESTClass()
{
    interval = new I()
    {
        left = 0,
        data = //Reads data property, 
        {
            value = 0 //set data.value to 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access sub-properties in object initializers using the member-access operator (`.`).

This works:

```
public class TESTClass<I, M>
       where I : IInterval<int, M>, new()
       where M : IData, new()
{ 
   public I interval{ set; get; }

   public TESTClass()
   {
       interval = new I() { left = 0, data = new M {value = 0} };
   }
}
```

Comment: But it does something noticeably different; it's not functionally identical code.

Comment: I'm assuming that this is what the OP intended. Even if `data.value=0` was allowed, from their code it would still raise a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Not if `I` initializes it, and it may well be important for `I` to do that if there is more that needs to be done when initializing it, after all not all types can have a sensible parameterless constructor.

Comment: I'm considering Sriram's and Mark's answer as "exactly" same thing; am I right ?

Comment: @Hamed No, My answer access existing `data` property where as this answer overwrites it with new instance. You could easily test it by removing the setter of `data` property `M data { get; }` and see. My answer will still work, mark's answer won't.

Comment: If I understood well, `new I()` makes an instance of data, then that instance is accessed by your code; and by Mark's answer it is replaced by a new instance. If so, Mark's solution seems doing a redundant work, unless there is a better explanation for it.

Comment: If `I`'s constructor initializes `data`, then my solution would overwrite that but my solution assumes that `data` is _not_ initialized.

Comment: `I`'s constructor initializes `data`, so I think Sriram's answer suits better. Thanks for your answer anyway ;-)